# Asus touchpad not working ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, touchpad

I have an Asus n750j laptop with kubuntu 18.04 installed but I can't do a two fingers scroll with the touchpad. This is the output of `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have installed Synaptics driver but still doesn't works

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

And when I go to `System Settings > Input Devices > Touchpad` I get the message `No touchpad found`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please check this link
[here](https://medium.com/@OrkoHunter/touchpad-problem-with-asus-laptop-on-linux-9bfbaeee1ae6) it solved the problem for touchpad

Answer (score 1):

The touchpad and function keys for my Asus ROG didn't work when using kernel version 4.15. I tried all sorts of stuff, the only thing that worked for me was to update my kernel.
check your kernel version using

> `$ uname -a`

Now after updating my kernel to `5.1.5` (latest at the time of writing) the touchpad started working along with the function keys.

You can use `ukuu` to update your kernel or manually downloading and installing. I would suggest you use ukuu as it is very easy to use.

Check this link for more info https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?103220-Is-your-ELAN1200-touchpad-not-working-on-Linux-D

Note: Make sure i2c-hid is not blacklisted and no ACPI parameters are supplied to GRUB.